Spacesuit for Vermoid Locomotion
The vermoid species resembles a short, stout earthworm (10cm long and 2cm wide) with two pairs of prehensile tentacles on the head, around 2cm in length. They move like an ordinary worm. They have a technological society with similar technology to modern day humanity
The issue is how well this mode of locomotion could work in space, specifically with a spacesuit: Could these vermoids create a spacesuit that allows them to crawl without needing mechanical aid? When using these suits they are primarily travelling through unpressurized tubular 'crawlways' in microgravity. Assume they can tolerate the same pressures/oxygen levels as a human being

How small are the Vermoid, themvelves? Prehensile tentacles of 2cm (0.79 in) is close to useless in the best of cases, but if the Vermoid are a meter long, they're really useless. Can the Vermoid spring, or must they move like worms? Because in an unpressurized environment without the ability to grab-and-swing or spring, everybody just sits there flailing about (not just worms). Unless they have jets? In which case their space suits look remarkably like sleeping bags.

When you say the Vermoids have modern human level tech, how do you explain them arriving at that level? Or are they simply using tech created by others? I.e., humans?

@JBH They can spring about (in microgravity) to the same degree that an earthworm could

That's a no, unless the earthworms in your area are more spry than those in mine.

@elemtilas They cannot tolerate unpressurised places without a spacesuit, which is why they need to wear a spacesuit while moving through these places

@JBH -- Maybe he's got Asian jumping worms?

@IchthysKing -- Sorry! I read that wrong! Disregard my last query.

Still need to address the source of their technology. I would argue that something the size and overall composition of a common garden slug won't be able to construct a space ship and thus wouldn't need a space suit. If you're arguing that that Vermoids are crew on someone else's ship, then you would have a viable question.

A human controlling a coffin-sized rocket ship with a few manipulator arms loses a lot of strength and functionality. A worm controlling a worm-coffin rocket ship with a few manipulator arms is going to gain a lot of strength and functionality. It's worth considering whether they'd even want something that looks like a worm space suit if we could wizard one up for them, as opposed to said tiny rocket ship with manipulator arms that is stronger, capable of more complex grabbing and manipulating, and a zillion times faster than their unsuited bodies.

Like a flexible mechanical counter pressure suit
Worms normally use expansion and contraction along the length of its body to 'worm' their way through soil.
In the early days of space exploration, there was investigation of the Mechanical Counter Pressure suit. Because it was realised that human skin is basically air-tight, all you need is a way to not have the internal volume of the body to expand beyond its limits, and a way to seal of the openings (eg our head).
Such research was to have a semi-flexible material allowing movement, but restricting overall volume expansion, allowing astronauts to move much more freely than air pressurised mechanical suits, with only the head requiring pressurisation:

In your case, your worms could have similar suits, using mechanical pressure to keep your worm from expanding in a vacuum, and then having enough flex to allow their bodies to expand and contract enough to 'worm their way' through your medium, and then only having a 'helmet' over their head / mouth and antennae/tentacles.

What was the downside that meant humans don't (yet?) use such suits?

@IMSoP The issue is each suit needs to be fitted exactly to the wearer. Any small gap / fold would produce sweat pooling / manoeuvring difficulties. As there is little tolerance available, the specific production of the suit to suit each astronauts unique figure is prohibitive as opposed to more generic volumetric suits that can be adapted to multiple wearers. In future, there may be fabrics and materials that allow more generic adaptability to multiple wearers, bringing predicted cost down per user, and this is an active topic of research (I think MIT produced a prototype recently).

Any shape you like - on the outside.
The inside functions as a vehicle control centre, a bit like an aircraft/gundam/autonomous-vehicle combo.
For some idea of what it might look like from their point-of-view, see Men in Black's "the Black Prince", an original pre-production sketch:

Copyright Universal Pictures, via monsterlegacy.net. Fair usage.

This is so much cooler than the "use a magnetic strip along the corridor and let them inch-worm along it" idea that I'm not even going to post an answer.

Build the crawlways to accommodate their movement
An accordion like pressure suit should be possible. Something like aluminum rings and some sort of vinil or latex to connect them. The main problem is that during an accordion compression cycle, the pressure in the suit would increase. There would have to be a device that allows air to flow into a tank when shrinking and back into the suit when extending. If your beings can overcome the strain of compressing the suit over an over again you can forgo it.
Now, design your tubes like ladders. And add hooks to the outside of the suits. The worms can then extend, hook on to the next rung and bring the rest of their body forward. Once contracted, hook the tail end for support then rinse and repeat.

Biological Option:
They are able to form symbiotic relationships.
They evolved in close contact with another species, intelligent, but not sapient. This secondary species is able to learn behaviors, and follow commands. Over time, first by selective breeding, then by technological means, the secondary species was able to be adapted to better serve their de-facto masters.
This doesn't signify that there is a relationship between them of master and slave, far more like a life-companion or favourite pet, but with the outstanding benefits that go beyond sheep-dogs or hunting-hawks -and far more close and emotionally invested.
The communication would at first have been perhaps through chemical control, like simulated pheromones or perhaps the control cordyceps has on an ant. Over time and with the help of technology, the communication could be more direct-neural to neural, by implant perhaps.
Of course, the cooperation between the species would remain supreme with the secondary species being allowed to frolic with it's own and engage in dreams and relationship building - on the occasions that their "masters" want to chill and binge-watch vids, maybe do a little relationship building of their own.
This would naturally allow for spacesuits that fit the secondary species, and their form of locomotion - whatever that may be. The design of them is up for grabs.

If you like it, should have put a ring around it.
As in, the core system is a gimbaled hollow ring, allowing for natural movement and transfer of that to the outside. Data streams in over some screen/HUD/display that follows the sensory head.
The outside can be all it wants. The only thing not taken care of - is social needs within the suit. What if communication makes it necessary to huddle together and exchange information by body contact? For that the suits need the ability to "merge" together and create shortlived communal spaces.
